# How can I generate the same checksum as artifactory?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, sha1, checksum, artifactory

As `art.exe` (the artifactory CLI interface) hangs whenever I call it from my build script, I am rewriting the bash script from their [page on the topic](https://www.jfrog.com/blog/artifactory-command-line-interface-cli-pure-and-simple/) in powershell 2.0. I'm using this code to generate my checksum:

```
$sha1 = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider
$path = Resolve-Path "CatVideos.zip"
$bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($path.Path)
$sha1.ComputeHash($bytes) | foreach { $hash = $hash + $_.ToString("X2") }

$wc=new-object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.Credentials= new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential("svnintegration","orange#5")
$wc.Headers.Add("X-Checksum-Deploy", "true")
$wc.Headers.Add("X-Checksum-Sha1", $hash)
```

The problem is it consistently produces a different checksum on my local than artifactory generates. It's not a 'corruption during transmission' error because I'm generating the checksum on my local and I've manually deployed several times.

How can I generate a checksum in the same manner as artifactory (2.6.5) so our checksums will match when I send mine and the deploy won't fail? Am I doing something obviously wrong when generating my checksum?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use

```
$wc.Headers.Add("X-Checksum-Sha1", $hash.ToLower())
```